# Complex numbers - prove true or false: $\operatorname{Re} (z/w) = 0.$

Tags: complex-numbers

I got the following:

Let $z$, $w$ be two complex numbers such that $\operatorname{Im}(w\cdot z) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(w\cdot z) > 0$.

I have to decide if the following is true:

$$\operatorname{Re} (z/w) = 0.$$

I think it's false, but I can't show it.

Comment: Do you have any counterexamples? Counterexamples can be used to show that something is false.

Comment: $w=1$ is a complex number.

Comment: @Element118 Yeah, I know. But I tried to find but failed...

Comment: @mikmik Which numbers did you try? The only way you can claim that you "tried" is if you tried at least $5$ different combinations of $z,w$.

Comment: What do you need to prove about RE(z/w)? That it is always 0, never 0, or could be 0?

Comment: After the big fat hint, "$w = 1$ is a complex number", I'm surprised _nobody_ mentioned $w = z = 1$, $wz = 1$, $\newcommand{\I}{\operatorname{Im}} \I(w\cdot z) = \I(1) = 0$, $\newcommand{\R}{\operatorname{Re}} \R(w\cdot z) = \R(1) > 0$, and $\R(z/w) = \R(1) \neq 0$. I suppose all the answers were already "in production" when that hint was dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$w = ae^{ib}$
and
$z = c e^{id}$,
where
$0 \le b, d < 2\pi
$.
Then
$wz = ac e^{i(b+d)}
$.

If
$Im(wz) = 0$,
then
$\sin(b+d) 
= 0$,
so
$b+d = k\pi$,
$0 \le k \le 3$.

If
$Re(wz)
> 0
$,
$\cos(b+d)
> 0
$.
Since $b+d = k\pi$,
$b+d = 2k\pi$
with
$k = 0$ or $1$
;
otherwise
$\cos(b+d) = -1
$.

$z/w
=(a/c)e^{i(d-b)}
$.
If
$Re(z/w) = 0$,
$\cos(d-b) = 0
=\cos(b-d)$,
so
$b-d = (j+1/2)\pi
$,
$-2 \le j \le 1
$.

Therefore
$b = (j/2+1/4+k)\pi
$
and
$d = (k-j-1/4)\pi
$.

To get a specific example,
set
$k = j = 0$
and
$a = c = 1$,
so that
$b = \pi/4$,
$d = -\pi/4$,
$w = e^{\pi i/4}$,
and
$z = e^{-\pi i/4}$.

Then
$wz = 1$
(so
$Im(wz) = 0$
and
$Re(wz) > 0$
)
and
$z/w = e^{\pi i/2}
= i$,
so
$Re(z/w) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

What about $z=2+i$ and $w=2-i$?

Answer (score 0):

Given $Im(w \times z) = 0$  and $Re(w \times z) > 0$, we have $w \times z = r$ for some positive real number $r$.

Then $z = r / w$.

What can we say about $Re(z / w) = Re(r / w^2) = r \times Re (w^{-2})$?

It can be anything you like.